# Text is truncating wrongly in Visual Foxpro database

Tags: visual-foxpro

In my application, I need to store a text in Visual Foxpro database. Actually, the max length of a text allowed in visual FoxPro is 255 characters. But in my application, it is allowing up to 88 characters only. I am connecting to the database using the FoxPro database driver. Version of the driver is VFPOLEDB.1

Comment: Yes, the MAX for a text field is 255, but the Data Table (not Database) structure overrides that with its own specific field setting.  It sounds as though the Field within the Data Table you are trying to write into is set to 88 characters.  You can use VFP to alter the Structure of the Data Table field.

Comment: Two things, first as Dhugalmac stated make sure the field length in the table is more than 88 characters, second,verify the text field where you're collecting the data is over 88 characters and is a TextArea not a Text field.

Comment: Another thing to take into consideration - is the VFP Data Table actively being used by another application?   If it is not being used by another application, then fine, go ahead and use VFP to change the field length.   However if it is being used you had better check on that application before considering to change the field length of the data table - you could cause it to "misbehave"

Comment: It is used by the other application and from there we are able to insert the data which is greater than the 255 char long(tried giving greater than 1000 chars). Am suspecting this might be memo field. How can we verify the data type of the field?

Comment: "How can we verify the data type of the field? "   Use VFP to examine the structure of the Data Table.

Comment: "It is used by the other application and from there we are able to insert the data which is greater than the 255 char long(tried giving greater than 1000 chars)"   It sounds like the other application is not writing to the same field as you want.   If the field were a Memo field, it would not be truncating your entries at 88 characters.   Perhaps you need to better understand the other application and what it is doing before moving forward.

Answer (score 4):

If the application is allowing more than 255 characters then it might be saving the data(which is greater than 88) to another table. Due to which in the application the total data is being displayed. Cross verify all the table related to that particular column.